# Is there a difference between commands "cp -P" and "cp -d"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cp

`man cp` says:

`-d` same as --no-dereference --preserve=links

`-P, --no-dereference` never follow symbolic links in SOURCE

I test these two options and find they are same in the practice. Both just keep the symbolic links regardless of whether the symbolic(soft) link is valid or not.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Note that questions about UNIX tools' command line usage generally belong on [unix.se] on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not Stack Overflow, unless the question is specific to scripted / non-interactive use. See the "*unique to* software development" clause in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, ANDed (not ORed) into other conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have the same effect on symbolic links. But `-d` has the additional effect of preserving hard links. That is, with `-d` or `--preserve=links`, if an invocation of `cp` encounters multiple links to the same file, it will create multiple links to the same file in the destination. Ordinarily `cp` doesn't pay attention to hard links and creates files that happen to have identical contents if two source files are hard links.

```
$ touch foo
$ ln foo bar
$ mkdir d; cp -d foo bar d
$ mkdir P; cp -P foo bar P
$ ls -log d P
P:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Apr 11 17:09 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 0 Apr 11 17:09 foo

d:
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 2 0 Apr 11 17:09 bar
-rw-rw-r-- 2 0 Apr 11 17:09 foo
```

Comment: Thank you very much.